django Channels / django restframework Pending task
I have a django channels projeto to handle a websocket connections, but some http request are blocking the app, and im receiving this error:

Application instance <Task pending name='Task-3739'
coro=<ProtocolTypeRouter.call() running at
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py:62>
wait_for=<Future pending cb=[shield.._outer_done_callback() at
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:864, Task.task_wakeup()]>>
for connection <WebRequest at 0x7efc603c8250 method=POST
uri=/charger_api/heartbeat/ clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to
shut down and was killed.

the entire comsumer are async and the rest part of django app is sync
this is my Comsumer
class ChargerSessionConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(args, kwargs)
      self.client_id = None
      self.group_name = None

   async def connect(self):
      self.client_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["client_id"]
      await self.channel_layer.group_add(
          self.group_name, self.channel_name
      )
      await self.accept()

   async def disconnect(self, close_code):
      await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)
      raise StopConsumer()

I try to raise to raise the stodComsumer ocording the documentation but the error percists
